# Why won't my ajax get json data request work?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, mobile, get

I'm writing a mobile app with phonegap and jquery mobile. I'm trying to get data from a server with this request which isn't working:

```
$.ajax({
        url : "https://localhost:8000/weatherData.json",
        type: "GET",
        dataType : "json",
        success: function(){

          $("#placeHold").text("hi");
          },

        error: function() {
          $("#placeHold").text("error");
          }

          });
 });
```

So I believe I already solved all my syntax errors, and I don't think it's a cross domain problem, since I'm on localhost and I already fixed that error. The URL is just JSON data and it goes to the right place in a browser. placeHold works, I get the word error in my document. I just do not understand why the data won't load. In chromes development tools I don't get an error, it just says failed goes red and displays this:

```
GET 'link'  jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
send                                         jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
p.extend.ajax                                jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
(anonymous function)                         firstpage.html:184
k                                            jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
l.fireWith                                   jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
p.extend.ready                               jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
D                                            jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
```

Comment: same origin also applies to ports ?

Comment: @adeneo That could be true, I once tried to send an email by posting a form with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to an SMTP server (don't ask why), but all browsers I tried it with (including IE) blocked the request because it used a non-standard port.

Comment: To be precise: `Error 312 (net::ERR_UNSAFE_PORT): unknown error`. I just translated it to English, so the exact wording might be different (only the first one and last two words were Dutch, so I doubt it, but just so you know).

Comment: "Protocols, domains and ports must match" is the usual error message in Chrome when encountering this issue

Comment: is your json a valid one?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this? You should tell PhoneGap to allow the Cross Origin Requests.

```
$( document ).bind( "mobileinit", function() {
    // Make your jQuery Mobile framework configuration changes here!

    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
});
```

See http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/phonegap.html.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to pass a parameter to your success or error function (like success: function(data))

I read a json file with this

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "../../js/languages/languages.json",
    async: isAsynchronous,
    success: function(data) {
        languageFile = data;
        }
```

I read an xml with this

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "xml",
    url: "../../config.xml",
    async: false,
    success: function(xml)
    {
        appVersion = $(xml).find("appVersion").text();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use `jsonp` or this: https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-jsonp

You can check this also [jQuery JSONP Tips and Tricks](https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-jsonp/blob/master/doc/TipsAndTricks.md).